# C++/SDL Inputs de teclado

Tags: c++

Tengo una pregunta referente al manejo de eventos en SDL. Todavia no tengo claro como funciona exactamente la pool de eventos de SDL y estoy teniendo problemas con el código que mostraré a continuación. Básicamente estoy intentando hacer que el personaje se mueva y pueda disparar a la vez. Pero si me muevo el personaje no puede disparar y viceversa. Entiendo que no se puede tener dos inputs al mismo tiempo o algo así, de nuevo no lo tengo del todo claro.

Aquí el código:

```
void Player::HandleEvents() {
    SDL_Event event;
    while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
        switch (event.type) {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            //Changes sense of vector when pressed
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w) {
                speedSenseY = -1; 
            } 
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_s) {
                speedSenseY = 1; 
            } 
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a) {
                speedSenseX = -1; 
            } 
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_d) {
                speedSenseX = 1;
            } 
            //Shooting
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP ) {
                if (!shooting) {
                    shooting = true;
                    //speed = 0;
                    Bullet* bullet = new Bullet();
                    bullet->speedSenseY = -1;
                    bullet->bulletRect.x = playerRect.x + (frameW / 2);
                    bullet->bulletRect.y = playerRect.y + (frameH / 2);
                    spawnedBullets.push_back(bullet);
                }

            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                 if (!shooting) {
                     shooting = true;
                    //speed = 0;
                     Bullet* bullet = new Bullet();
                     bullet->speedSenseY = 1;
                     bullet->bulletRect.x = playerRect.x + (frameW / 2);
                     bullet->bulletRect.y = playerRect.y + (frameH / 2);
                     spawnedBullets.push_back(bullet);
                 }

            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
                 if (!shooting) {
                     shooting = true;
                     //speed = 0;
                     Bullet* bullet = new Bullet();
                     bullet->speedSenseX = -1;
                     bullet->bulletRect.x = playerRect.x + (frameW / 2);
                     bullet->bulletRect.y = playerRect.y + (frameH / 2);
                     spawnedBullets.push_back(bullet);
                 }
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                 if (!shooting) {
                     shooting = true;
                     //speed = 0;
                     Bullet* bullet = new Bullet();
                     bullet->speedSenseX = 1;
                     bullet->bulletRect.x = playerRect.x + (frameW / 2);
                     bullet->bulletRect.y = playerRect.y + (frameH / 2);
                     spawnedBullets.push_back(bullet);
                 }
            }
        break;

        case SDL_KEYUP:
            //Sets speed to 0 when not pressed
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_w && speedSenseY  0) {
                speedSenseY = 0; 
            } 
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_a && speedSenseX  0) {
                speedSenseX = 0; 
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_UP) {
                shooting = false;
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_DOWN) {
                shooting = false;
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_LEFT) {
                shooting = false;
            }
            if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_RIGHT) {
                shooting = false;
            }
        break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La pool de eventos de SDL no es mas que una lista de los eventos que ocurrieron en determinado Frame en tu aplicación, por ejemplo si en el Frame X tu mueves tu mouse se añade a la lista de eventos el evento SDL_MOUSEMOTION y si por ejemplo en el mismo frame presionas 2 teclas, se añadiran dos eventos del tipo SDL_KEYDOWN con la información correspondiente de las tecla dentro del evento (event.key.keysym.sym), con lo que a menos de que hayan sucedido otros eventos durante el mismo frame (window, joystick, etc.) tu
`while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))`  solo se ejecutara 3 veces y en cada iteración `event.type` sera del tipo SDL_MOUSEMOTION, SDK_KEYDOWN y SDK_KEYDOWN (no necesariamente en ese orden). Con lo cuál llegamos a la conclución de que si se pueden tener varias inputs al mismo tiempo.

Por otro lado hay que tener en cuenta que SDK_KEYDOWN y SDL_KEYUP son eventos que se desencadenan solo una vez. Por ejemplo si tú en el Frame 10 presionas la tecla 'x' se agregara el evento correspondiente (SDL_KEYDOWN) a la pool de eventos, sin embargo si mantiens presionada la tecla en el Frame 11 el evento ya no se agregara  a la pool hasta que sueltes la tecla y vuelvas a presionarla. Para lograr que tu logica se ejecute siempre mientras mantienes presionada X tecla puedes hacer 2 cosas .

1.- Llamar a la funcion `SDL_EnableKeyRepeat` la cuál provocara que el evento SDK_KEYDOWN se agregue a la lista de eventos siempre que la tecla se encuentre presionada.

2.- Utilizar la función SDL_GetKeyState la cuál te retorna un arreglo con el estado de todas las teclas

Ambos casos te simplificarían el codigo ya que no tendrias que estar revisando si ya dejo de presionar X tecla para dejar de moverte o disparar con lo cuál tu codigo te quedaría más o menos así:

Utilizando SDL_GetKeyState

```
//Get keys state
Uint8 *keystates = SDL_GetKeyState( NULL ); 

//Reset speed
speedSenseX = speedSenseY = 0;

if (keystates[SDLK_w]) {
  speedSenseY = -1;
}
else if(keystates[SDLK_s) {
  speedSenseY = 1;
}

if (keystates[SDLK_a]) {
  speedSenseX = -1;
}
else if(keystates[SDLK_d]) {
  speedSenseX = 1;
}

shooting = keystates[SDLK_UP] || keystates[SDLK_DOWN] || keystates[SDLK_LEFT] || keystates[SDLK_RIGHT];

if (shooting) {
  Bullet* bullet = new Bullet();

  if (keystates[SDLK_UP]) {
    bullet->speedSenseY = -1;
  }
  else if(keystates[SDLK_DOWN) {
    bullet->speedSenseY = 1;
  }
  else if (keystates[SDLK_LEFT]) {
    bullet->speedSenseX = -1;
  }
  else if(keystates[SDLK_RIGHT]) {
    bullet->speedSenseX = 1;
  }

  bullet->bulletRect.x = playerRect.x + (frameW / 2);
  bullet->bulletRect.y = playerRect.y + (frameH / 2);
  spawnedBullets.push_back(bullet);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la explicación ha sido de mucha ayuda!